# Getting the current time zone in android application

Tags: java, android

How can I get the current time zone in my Android application? I tried to use this

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance( userConfig.locale);
TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();
```

But I am not getting the timezone from it. How can I display the timezone?

Comment: If you use `JodaTime`, you can use `DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.getDefault() );`. If you're not using `JodaTime`, you should check it out.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Use this

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();
Log.d("Time zone","="+tz.getDisplayName());
```

or you can also use the `java.util.TimeZone` class

```
TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName()
```

Comment: +1 for using TimeZone.getDefault() instead of instantiating a Calendar just to get the timezone.

Comment: `TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName()` works well.

Answer (score 31):

```
String timezoneID = TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
System.out.println(timezoneID);
```

In my Console, it prints `Asia/Calcutta`

And any Date Format, I set it Like....

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
sdf2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezoneID));
```

Answer (score 18):

I needed the offset that not only included day light savings time but as a numerial.  Here is the code that I used in case someone is looking for an example.

I get a response of "11" which is what I would expect in NSW,Australia in summer.  I also needed it as a string so I could post it to a server so you may not need the last line.

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
Date now = new Date();
int offsetFromUtc = tz.getOffset(now.getTime()) / 3600000;
String m2tTimeZoneIs = Integer.toString(offsetFromUtc);
```

Comment: This won't work for timezones that fall under half hour differences such as Newfoundland which is GMT-2:30, you would simply get 2 back

Answer (score -10):

To display the current time, you should run below code snippet on the UI thread. This worked for me:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();          
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {          
    public void run() {      
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){      
            public void run() {      
                dateTxt.setText(new Date().toString());      
            }      
        });      
    }      
}, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: Please read and understand the question @gangeshwari